# How put all rows heights to 20, and all columns width to 30

Tags: python, pandas

I want to put all row heights to 20 and all column widths to 30. I tried this code: All is just with pandas dataframe.

```
worksheet2.set_default_row(20) #it works but in Excel is it 19.80
worksheet2.set_default_column(30) #it doesn't work, 

Error: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_default_column'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Creating excel file

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# creating and saving excel file
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 4)),
    columns=['column name 1', 'column name 2',
             'column name 3', 'column name 4']
)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_sheet', index=False)
writer.save()
```

## Changing size of columns and rows

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test_file.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_sheet', index=False)

worksheet = writer.sheets['my_sheet']

# change column width of all columns
worksheet.set_column(0, len(df),  30)

# change row height
for row in range(0, len(df.index)+1):
    worksheet.set_row(row, 20)

writer.save()
```

## Before

[image]

## After

[image]

## Reference

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html

You might also want to take a look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-auto-adjust-the-width-of-excel-columns-with-pandas-excelwriter-60cee36e175e) to dynamically change the row height and column width

Comment: Sorry my question is different, I want to put all rows heights to 20, and all columns width to 30

Comment: sorry I initially misunderstood the question. I modified my answer.